# How to get the html List value through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am trying to get values from html list `<li>`.

```
<ul>
    <li><a>Main Menu</a>
        <ul class="leftbutton" >
            <li value="List1"><a>Sampe 1</a></li>
            <li value="List2"><a>Sample 2</a></li>
            <li value="List3"><a>Sample 3</a></li>
            <li value="List4"><a>Sample 4</a></li>
            <li value="List5"><a>Sample 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul> 

<iframe id="iframeid" width="100%" height="100%" align="middle"></iframe> 

function changeList()
{
    var iframe = document.getElementById("iframeid");  
    var url = document.getElementById("selectedlist").value + ".html"; 
    iframe.src = url;
}
```

Where would I put `onClick="changeList()"` to get the values from the list?

Comment: With the click on a list I want to load an html page into an iframe (instead of opening a new html page).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get several things wrong here.

1. a HTML list item (`<li>`) does not have a value
2. a HTML list has no "selected item"
3. you cannot get any "selected" item by calling `getElementById()`

Here is my alternative suggestion:

```
<ul>
  <li><a>Main Menu</a>
    <ul class="leftbutton" >
      <li><a href="List1.html" onclick="return changeList(this);">Sample 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="List2.html" onclick="return changeList(this);">Sample 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="List3.html" onclick="return changeList(this);">Sample 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="List4.html" onclick="return changeList(this);">Sample 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="List5.html" onclick="return changeList(this);">Sample 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul> 

<iframe id="iframeid" width="100%" height="100%" align="middle"></iframe> 

<script type="text/javascript">
function changeList(a)
{
  var iframe = document.getElementById("iframeid");
  iframe.src = a.href;
  return false;
}
</script>
```

Thoughts: If JavaScript is deactivated, it still works (rudimentarily). The function returns `false`, so when JavaScript is enabled clicking on the link cancels the href navigation.

Be aware that up to HTML 4.01 Transitional it is also possible to do this entirely without JavaScript. A `target` attribute with the frame name is sufficient:

```
<ul>
  <li><a>Main Menu</a>
    <ul class="leftbutton" >
      <li><a href="List1.html" target="iframename">Sample 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="List2.html" target="iframename">Sample 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="List3.html" target="iframename">Sample 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="List4.html" target="iframename">Sample 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="List5.html" target="iframename">Sample 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul> 

<iframe id="iframeid" name="iframename" width="100%" height="100%" align="middle"></iframe>
```

Comment: Both solutions worked :-D. I prefer the javascript-less one with the target attribute.

Comment: Good to hear. This is the more portable solution in any case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure about inline iframes but you could simply use

```
<li><a href="/path/to/html" target="myIframeId">Value</a></li>
```

This isn't valid html 4 strict but is valid with transitional and works in all browsers regardless.

Comment: You target frame names, not ids (and iframes aren't in Strict either, so needing Transitional to use the target attribute doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

`li` has attribute value, but the value should be an integer, that is the point:

```
             <li value="1"><a>Sampe 1</a></li>
            <li value="2"><a>Sample 2</a></li>
            <li value="3"><a>Sample 3</a></li>
            <li value="4"><a>Sample 4</a></li>
            <li value="5"><a>Sample 5</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would put this on the anchor tag, as I assume that is what you are clicking.